# Using a touch screen 24inch monitor to control phone functions

Tags: android, input, mapping, touchscreen

I have a cable that mirrors the display on my phone to a 24inch touchscreen computer. Would it be possible to program software to allow a touch input on the computer monitor to act as an equivalent touch input on the phone?
for example touching the message icon on the monitor would result in the message app opening because the programmed software maps the computer touchscreen to the phone touchscreen.
Both my monitor and phone have the same number of pixels (1920 x 1080).

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. you have 1920x1080 on your phone?

Comment: yes I have the sony xperia z

Comment: I don't know about rolling it yourself.  Of course, pretty much anything is possible with Android but seems like quite a project.  Check out this Japanese company which unveiled a commercial product which is pretty much what you are looking for (http://vr-zone.com/articles/skr-technology-unveils-32-inch-multi-touch-android-based-digital-signage-display/12877.html?TB_iframe=true&height=650&width=850).  Tried to find some more info on their website but it's all in Japanese.  This may be the actual product now (http://www.skr-tech.co.jp/BIGandroidTouchsystem.htm).